# Making background image over all page conent?

Tags: css

On my website, I am having a dilemma. [(This website)](http://www.wychelmstudios.com). On the homepage the background is across the whole page (which is what I want), where as on the contact page it is not. I have made it transparent using:

```
#siteWrapper{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
```

However, this only turns it black? On the header of the page, there is the image but not on the background of the body? I can do it the other way around so the body has an image and the header does not (like this):

```
#siteWrapper{
  background-image: url("http://static.squarespace.com/static/545d45afe4b08eea0ac65e7a/t/54612b8ae4b0ca233d43bdee/141565    4282657/Website%20Background%20Trees.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

However I would like it so the image covers all of the page (header and body background) - Thanks

**ADDITION**

I tried to use `background-size: cover;` however that only covered the footer and not the header (as well as stretched the image).

Answer (score 1):

You can put the background-image on your `body` element, and set `background-size:100%`, and remove it as the background image from the other elements which it is on. This will work on all page across the site.

Comment: By targeting the body element `body { background-image: url('etc'); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; }`

Comment: Oh right, that has not worked I am afraid. It has changed the background image, however everything else is in the foreground and not transparent which it is set to.

Comment: Did you try to set the background-color of the body to rgba(0,0,0,0) like you did on the #siteWrapper?

Comment: Yes, it only changes the very back image. The content is in front of that.

Comment: I see that you have background-color for the body on your sites contact page set to #000, which is black. And on #siteWrapper also, is black, #100806. Try changing that to the rgba(0,0,0,0)

Comment: I have done that before, I just made it go back to default. I can put an image on the background for the main content and it will look fine. However the header does not get that image. (I will update it so it is like this)

Comment: It seems that your relatively position header is pushing down the body content. Not having access to the code, I can't really troubleshoot more than I have already.

Comment: Oh ok, is there no way to just put the image over the header as well as the main content somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything in your footer so you can just get rid of the footer all together to have the image take up 100% of the webpage with your code above.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it's the header that does not have the image in it. I believe I can remove the footer with `#footer { display :none; }`.